# .content in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am new to Python development and Python requests.

I have this code:

```
import requests
from pattern import web
import re
import pandas as pd


def list_of_prices(url):
    html = requests.get(url).text
    dom = web.DOM(html)
    list = []
    for person in dom('.freelancer-list-item .medium.price-tag'):
        currency = person('sup')
        amount = person('span')
        list.append([currency[0].content if currency else 'na', 
                     amount[0].content if amount else 'na'])
    return list

list_of_prices('http://www.peopleperhour.com/freelance/data+analyst#page=2')
```

When I run this code i get an error like `module pattern not found`, but that's not what I'm asking for help with.

Where does `.content` come from? Is it used only with Python requests?

Comment: I'm sorry to have to say that, but the answer is obvious just reading the code. The interesting lines are `from pattern import web` and `dom = web.DOM(html)`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers is .content only used with python requests ?

Comment: @user3852154 why do you keep ignoring what people are telling you and repeating the question? Bruno told you exactly where that attribute is coming from, it has nothing to do with requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the module pattern:

`pip install pattern`

`requests` has a content property and so does `pattern`. 
If you don't have pip installed, download the zip [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/Pattern/pattern-2.6.zip), run run the `setup.py` file in the directory with `python setup.py install`.

**Note** *Pattern is written for Python 2.5+ (no support for Python 3 yet).*

Comment: can you please tell me ..is .content used in case of requests ??

Comment: @user3852154, you are iterating over `dom = web.DOM(html)` so `currency[0].content` is using the content from the pattern module. Your error is because you don't have that module installed

Comment: when i use pattern module it throws syntax error like  File "C:\Python34\lib\pattern\web\__init__.py", line 120
    except Exception, e:

Comment: am running python 3.04

Comment: the pattern module only seems to work for python 2, the setup.py script contains pyhton 2 syntax that won't work in python 3

Comment: so as like you said is .content used with pattern module ??

Comment: i mean is .content property used with the pattern module ??

Comment: yes, the main part of the code is using `dom = web.DOM(html)` so without the pattern module you are not going to be doing much with that code